# Android requestFocus() skipping edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to programmatically designate where the focus goes when a  user presses the next button on the keyboard. I can get it to work for some, but I have one case where the view gets skipped and the view below it gets the focus.

I went into debugger and the focus does go through my view, but then jumps to the last one. Below is a small diagram of what I'm talking about.

```
(1) EditText 
(2) AutoCompleteEditText
(3) EditText
(4) EditText
(1) -> (2) is ok
(2) -> (3) doesn't work, it does (2) -> (3) -> (4), where it briefly go to (3)
if I start at (3), then (3) -> (4) is ok.
```

This is how I am setting the focus

```
view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            view.clearFocus();
            nextView.requestFocus();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
view.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                view.clearFocus();
                nextView.requestFocus();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Found the solution. If anyone else is having this issue, just change ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_UP so your code is only triggered when the press is complete. I'm guessing with ACTION_DOWN, there are multiple calls made. But I'm not sure.